# Put aside. Play your doll after this

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

He was taking her octopus doll while I reading him a story.

"***Put aside.*** Play your doll after this."

I was asking him to put his doll aside.

Does it sound natural to a native speaker.

Comment: To write you a good answer, we need to know more about the research you've already done to find an answer yourself. [This page](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700) has a lot of information on how to write an excellent question on ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your sentence doesn't make sense as there is no subject. You can either specify it directly:

> Put **your doll** aside.

Or you can use the pronoun *it*, which seems a better fit for this sentence. Note that you also need to include the word **with** for this sentence to make sense grammatically.

> Put **it** aside. Play **with** your doll after this.